# Modify required flag of field in Django Class Based View

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have following model used in my Django CBV CreateView:

```
class Agreement(BaseModel):
    offer = models.ForeignKey(Offer, null=True, blank=True)

    owner_name = models.CharField(), max_length=15, null=True, blank=False)
    has_second_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    second_owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
```

And form:

```
class AgreementForm(BootstrapFormMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Agreement
        fields = ('owner_name', 'has_second_owner', 'second_owner_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-5'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-7'
        self.helper.field_template = 'bootstrap3/layout/inline_field.html'
        self.helper.form_id = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('owner_name'),
            Field('has_second_owner'),
            Field('second_owner_name'),

        )
```

I am using CreateView to crate instances of Agreement model. By default, `second_owner_name` isn't required (because `has_second_owner` is False).

In case user change `has_second_owner` field I have to modify `second_owner_name` field to be required in the view.

How should I do this? What is a proper method to modify fields depending on POST data? Thank you

Comment: You can write a `field_clean()` method in your model form for custom validations

Comment: Do I have to do this in model? Can't I just modify form in view to make particular fields required or not?

Comment: You can do that. But the best way to deal with this situation is to write your validations in your form. You can check this link for helping yourself. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other